# Dynamic binding in XAMGrid

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, infragistics

I want to bind data to a (Infragistics Silverlight) XamGrid.

The problem is that the content of the data source (columns and content itself) is variable and I only know it at run time.

I have implemented an ObservableCollection according to this web site 
http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/04/binding-a-silverlight-datagrid-to-dynamic-data-via-idictionary/ to the silverlight datagrid, but it doesn't seem to work for the xamgrid.

Is it possible to implement a data source (ItemsSource in this case) with dynamic data?

What changes should I make to the solution presented in the web site, in order for it to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: found this at infragistics online help, hope this helps: Auto Generate Columns http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/Silverlight/2011.2/CLR4.0/?page=xamGrid_Auto_Generate_Columns.html

Answer (score 0):

If your objects are accessible with string indexers you can bind to them
http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/Silverlight/Current/CLR4.0/?page=xamGrid_Support_for_String_Indexers.html